# Weight distribution of vectors with elements taken from different sets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose we have a positive integer $m$ and $t$ non-negative integers $m_i$, $i=1,2,...,t$, such that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^t {{m_i}}  = m$. Consider the set of vectors of length $m$ created as follows. Each of the first $m_1$ elements can be taken from the set $\{0,1\}$. Each of the elements out of the next $m_2$ elements is taken from the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and so on, such that the last $m_t$ elements are taken from the set $\{0,1,2,...,2^t-1\}$.

For example, if $m=2$, $m_1=1$ and $m_2=1$, the set contains the vectors $\left[ {0,0} \right],\left[ {0,1} \right],\left[ {0,2} \right],\left[ {0,3} \right],\left[ {1,0} \right],\left[ {1,1} \right],\left[ {1,2} \right]$ and $\left[ {1,3} \right]$.

My question is, out of the vectors in a set for given $m_1,...,m_t$, how many have $j$ non-zero elements $\left(j=0,1,2,...,m\right)$ (i.e., *weight* $j$)?

The answer for $j=0$ is of course $1$. For $j=1$ it is $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^t {{m_i} \cdot \left( {{2^i} - 1} \right)}$. But what happens for larger values of $j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is given by
$$ \sum_{\vec {\lambda}} \prod_{i=1}^t \binom {m_i}{\lambda_i} \left( 2^i - 1 \right)^{\lambda_i}, $$
where the sum is over all vectors $\vec {\lambda} = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_t) $ of nonnegative integers satisfying $\sum_i \lambda_i = j $.

The $\vec {  \lambda} $ accounts for which parts contain the nonzero entries, the $ \binom {m_i}{\lambda_i}$ factors are from choosing the exact positions of these entries, and the $ \left( 2^i - 1 \right)^{\lambda_i}$ factors from the choices of the nonzero entries.

I don't think there's a nice closed form for this.

Comment: But $\lambda_i$ can be greater than $m_i$, how do you interpret ${m_i \choose \lambda_i}$ in this case?

Comment: $\binom{m_i}{\lambda_i}$ is defined to be $0$ when $\lambda_i > m_i$, so these terms do not affect the sum.  From a computational point of view, you could add the restrictions $\lambda_i \le m_i$, but mathematically it does not affect the outcome.